# Send Push Notifications Android No Server

Tags: android, notifications, push

I am not a pro android programmer. I am trying to send push notifications to all users that have my app installed on their devices. The problem is that I do not have a server and just want to send them a message that will pop up on their phones. I have set-up Google APIs already.

I tried to use pushbots.com, however, it does not work when the app is not running on the background, then it crashes. Then, I am trying to implement it in a different way. I am researching this for days now and I need help.

Is there a way that I can send notifications messages without having a server? I heard that I may use google services somehow, any thoughts?

Comment: try this http://developer.xtify.com/display/sdk/Getting+Started+with+Google+Cloud+Messaging

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. It looks pretty much as pushbot. Does xtify have problems when the device is not running?

Answer (score 0):

This will help you out!!

http://developer.xtify.com/display/sdk/Getting+Started+with+Google+Cloud+Messaging

Push messages aren't received when the app is force closed.

That is expected behavior for pushing to Android devices.  If the Xtify-enabled app is force-closed then a push message sent via GCM will not be received.The Xtify service will be restarted and messages will be received when the user re-opens the app or the user restarts his/her device.

Comment: That would be sufficient for me. As long as it does not crash it is fine and if it sends later on when the app is reopened I will accept the answer. Working on it right now, thanks once again!

Comment: I am not receiving any notifications unfortunately. This Xtify is very similar to pushbots. However, xtify isn't working at all!

Comment: I was before. But it was because I had some old code from pushbots. Since I removed the pushbot code from the xml and my activities, then I got rid of the errors. The application is running fine now. I created a notification on the Xtify website, but haven't received any notification yet...

Comment: have you changed the Api key?

Comment: @GustavoBaiocchiCosta go to your https://code.google.com/apis/console  and check reports see if there is any activity

Comment: use the same key on xtify server as the one you have used in your app

Comment: final String XTIFY_APP_KEY = "xxx";
    final String PROJECT_NUM = "xxx"; // This is the    Google Project Number
    XtifySDK.start(getApplicationContext(), XTIFY_APP_KEY, PROJECT_NUM);

Comment: Just leave it, I am moving on, it won't work. Thanks for your help!